# putting regex as key in redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis

I am new to redis and want to solve a problem using it.  I want to store a set of filters (regular expression) as key into redis, so when  a stream data comes and matches any of these filter, gets its corresponding value.

I am confused how to solve this using redis data structure .

Comment: Redis is NOT designed for this kind of work. You need other tools or implement it yourself

Comment: Maybe one of the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) commands could help, but I'm not sure to fullly understand your problem. These commands support pattern matching using a syntax described [here](http://redis.io/commands/keys)